# ISPConfig install.php fails (can't load msql.so)

Tags: centos, nginx, php

I have  a centos 5.3 server, running nginx and I am trying to install ISPConfig.

This is the point of failing:

```
-bash-3.2# php -q install.php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/module/msql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: install.php
```

This confuses me as I am unsure why php is not already running.
I am using php-fpm, does that replace php in this instance?

Status of php-fpm shows this:

```
-bash-3.2# service php status
php: unrecognized service
-bash-3.2# service php-fpm status
php-fpm dead but subsys locked
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the php-mysql package
(`yum install php-mysql`)
and you have enabled the extension in php.ini (`extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so` line is exists and not commented out).

Comment: file /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), stripped
file exists... I have added that line, but the error persists. 
Now followed by this line:
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: commented out this line:
 extension=msql.so
and the error changed to just: 
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: install.php

Comment: Thanks that was it, reading further into php.ini showed that the file gets loaded from /etc/php.d/mysql.ini so I added it there and all was good. (I also had to switch into the install dir, duh)